# How can I solve the Poisson PDE efficiently and fast in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, 3d

I am trying to *numerically* solve the Possion PDE in cylindrical coordinate system.

$$\Delta f = {1 \over \rho} {\partial \over \partial \rho} \left(\rho {\partial f \over \partial \rho} \right) + {1 \over \rho^2} {\partial^2 f \over \partial \phi^2} + {\partial^2 f \over \partial z^2} = g$$

There are some C libraries including MKL that solves Poisson equation in 3D Cartesian very fast by Fourier. Unfortunately, I could not find any libraries for cylindrical Poisson and I need to develop one by myself. Could someone help me what method I should use to be able to have the solution efficiently and fast?

The boundary conditions are standard Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions. I mainly use Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: You wanna use Fourier transform to solve the Poisson equation *numerically* under cylindrical coordinate system. Am I reading this right?

Comment: @Shuhao, you are right. I want to solve it *numerically*. Is Fourier transform in cylindrical coordinate system as fast as the one in 3D Cartesian? Aren't the nonlinearities a problem in Possion PDE in cylindrical?

Comment: What do your boundary conditions look like?  Are they standard Dirichlet and Neumann type conditions?

Comment: @rajb245, yes they are standard Dirichlet and Neumann type boundary conditions.

Comment: I mainly work with Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer?